# How to change dictionary keys only? Without change values swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have array like this.

```
var Array = [Int:[String:Any]]()
```

I just update the values

```
 let updateValue = ["Name":tripName!,"date":firstDate,"year":year,"startData":startDateValue,"endDate":endDateValue,"countryName":countrname!,"totelBudjet":totelBudjet,"backgroundImage":arrImages[randomItem],"code":getAddtripeAttibutes.code,"countryIcon":countryIcon] as [String : Any]

 Array.updateValue(updateValue, forKey: tripId)

 tripId = tripId + 1
```

> We have more Array data as mentioned below
>
> trip keys like :
>
> [0] [1] [2]

```
[0: ["year": "2019", "tripName": "Test", "backgroundImage": "Europe_Trip", "code": "DZD", "startData": 2019-05-30 10:14:11 +0000, "date": "May 30 - May 31", "endDate": 2019-05-31 10:14:11 +0000, "totelBudjet": "5000 DZD", "countryIcon": "dz", "countryName": "Algeria"], 1: ["date": "May 30 - May 31", "backgroundImage": "Europe_Trip", "endDate": 2019-05-31 10:14:43 +0000, "code": "DZD", "countryName": "Algeria", "tripName": "Gg", "countryIcon": "dz", "totelBudjet": "500 DZD", "startData": 2019-05-30 10:14:43 +0000, "year": "2019"], 2: ["year": "2019", "backgroundImage": "Asia_Trip", "endDate": 2019-05-31 10:15:00 +0000, "countryIcon": "al", "totelBudjet": "5800 ALL", "code": "ALL", "tripName": "Bb", "countryName": "Albania", "date": "May 30 - May 31", "startData": 2019-05-30 10:15:00 +0000]]
```

*I have updated tableview with above data*

> after i delete one array [1] it look like:
>   this
>
> [0] [2]

```
 [0: ["year": "2019", "tripName": "Test", "backgroundImage": "Europe_Trip", "code": "DZD", "startData": 2019-05-30 10:14:11 +0000, "date": "May 30 - May 31", "endDate": 2019-05-31 10:14:11 +0000, "totelBudjet": "5000 DZD", "countryIcon": "dz", "countryName": "Algeria"], 2: ["year": "2019", "backgroundImage": "Asia_Trip", "endDate": 2019-05-31 10:15:00 +0000, "countryIcon": "al", "totelBudjet": "5800 ALL", "code": "ALL", "tripName": "Bb", "countryName": "Albania", "date": "May 30 - May 31", "startData": 2019-05-30 10:15:00 +0000]]
```

> But I want to update the keys as [0][1] not as [0][2]

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: I would suggest using a custom type(e.g, Trip) to represent the trip data and create `tableView` dataSource as `var array = [Trip]()`.

Comment: @Kamran right on. His data looks like JSON. So he could probably make a `Trip` struct which could conform `Codable`.

Comment: you can use the `enumerated()` method which actually adds an _index_ to each element dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you trying to mimic an array using a dictionary?

If you have an array like this.

```
var array: [[String: Any]] = [["year": "2019"], ["year": "2020"], ["year": "2021"]] // Minimalistic example array
```

You can delete values at that particular location and it'll give you what you need currently.

```
array.remove(at: 1)
print(array[1])
```

> ["year": "2021"]

---

**Note** - Your data looks like JSON response. So, you could use [@Kamran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395636/kamran)'s suggestion in the comments and use a struct `Trip` conforming `Decodable` and directly get your data as an array of `Trip`s. However, if your JSON is formatted with keys 0, 1, 2... then your JSON is really bad and you should get it changed if you can. If you can't, you'll have to change the dictionary of dictionaries to an array of dictionary or better yet array of structs.

Comment: I want to retrieve array data with key.

Comment: Bingo. I will not even bother to write an answer myself. `Mimic` is the proper word to use here.

Comment: Use the index as subscript? array[1]?

Comment: [0: ["year": "2019", "tripName": "we"]
0 is key
with that key only I can find year and trip and more details.

Comment: @ManikandanS you can use `array[0]` to get `["year": "2019", "tripName": "we"] `

Answer (score 0):

it is not quite clear to me what's the use-case here, so I'm trying to cover the most possible.

---

#### using `enumerated()` on the array

if you need only to add the index, call the `enumerated()` method on an array, like e.g.

```
var array: [[String: Any]] = [["year": "2019", "tripName": "Trip#1"], ["year": "2020", "tripName": "Trip#2"], ["year": "2021", "tripName": "Trip#3"]]

array.enumerated().forEach { (arg0) in
    let (offset, element) = arg0
    debugPrint("\(offset) : \(element)")
}
```

that would assign an *offset* to each element which you can print out or use otherwise, in my example the output on the console would look like this:

```
0 : ["tripName": "Trip#1", "year": "2019"]
1 : ["tripName": "Trip#2", "year": "2020"]
2 : ["tripName": "Trip#3", "year": "2021"]
```

if you need to actually remove an item, like e.g.

```
array.remove(at: 1)
```

and call the same snippet (above) again, it assigns the *offset* like this:

```
0 : ["tripName": "Trip#1", "year": "2019"]
1 : ["tripName": "Trip#3", "year": "2021"]
```

that is quite similar to what you might looking for.

---

#### mapping an array from dictionary

if you need to actually map the dictionary first into an array (like e.g. during post-processing a `JSON` response), you may go for that as well like e.g.:

```
var dictionary: [Int: [String: Any]] = [0: ["year": "2019", "tripName": "Trip#1"], 1: ["year": "2020", "tripName": "Trip#2"], 2: ["year": "2021", "tripName": "Trip#3"]]

var array = dictionary.map { $0.value }
```

then you can start dealing with the `enumerated()` method just like I shown it to you above.

---

***NOTE:** obviously if you do the mapping like I did, you will lose the information what the original key holds, and that will be replaced coincidently with the same number in my example, which may be misleading but if you are aware of that the `offset` and the `key` are two completely different values here, you may not have a huge surprise after you do the mapping.*